# GlassFish 3.1 and the tag <url-pattern> of web.xml file

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, web.xml

I read that into the tag `<url-pattern>` I can write a prefix or a suffix pattern url.

But if I try to write something like:

```
<url-pattern>*sde</url-pattern>
```

or

```
<url-pattern>/sde*</url-pattern>
```

and try to get the url as polsde alsde or sdepp sdelop I have a 404 error and a deploy failed
into server log.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! From reading the 3.0 servlet spec, it doesn't look like the wildcard in servlet mappings works the same way as a regex wildcard; there are boundaries to the mapping.

*.sde would be a valid mapping.

So would "/sde/*", but I don't see any mention of embedded wildcards as you're using them. For the Servlet 3.0 specification, see section 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

URL-pattern is wrong.

The pattern you have supplied is invalid

The url-pattern specification:

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’
>     suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
>     mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>     servlet of the application. In this
>     case the servlet path is the request
>     URI minus the context path and the
>     path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

- Please refer [Java Servlet Specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html)